# Plotting double digit CSV's

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to plot a series of CSV's from the latest data (2 March):

collection_date ='2021-03-02'
'2021-03-02':{'probe':'old','transects':[0,2,4,6,8,10,12]}

I have saved some of these files as double-digit indexes (so for example, 2021-03-02_10), and I am facing an issue. When I initially try to call them up, the 0, 2, 4, 6 and 8 indexed-files show up, but 10 and 12 don't.

I then tried to save the index names of these CSV files to 00, 02, 04, 06 and 08 to take into account the double digits, but instead I receive an empty list. I can send a copy of the notebook if it helps, but does anyone have suggestions for how I can fix this problem?

Comment: I'm using the following code to call up each file from that day into a list (the 'aquaread_transects' is the folder I have saved these CSV's in):

lookup_file_list('../aquaread_transects', collection_date, tidecor=False)

Comment: To further clarify, this 2 March data is as part of a list of other similar data points which dates from April 2020, and ideally has 7 points i.e. :

2020-10-10':{ 'probe':'old','transects':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].

Comment: Sam, you can use the [edit] button to include extra information into your question, better than trying to add it as a comment.

Comment: Good to know, thanks @MartinEvans